# Map network drive - The network path could not be found

Tags: networking, windows-10, mapped-drive

I am trying map a network drive from Windows 10 to my Android phone by following these instructions: [map Android to Windows drive](https://www.guidingtech.com/39472/map-android-drive-windows/). I'm running WebDAV server on the phone, but when I try to map the drive, Windows says `The network path \\192.168.0.11:8080 could not be found`.

I'm able map a path on another Windows machine via both its name and its IP address. I can also browse the phone's files via my browser in Windows.

What's stopping Windows from mapping the path?

Comment: It’s been so long since I used a mapped drive to a WebDav server I forgot most everything. But some quick research reminded me how difficult it was. I’m fairly positive those instructions you linked to are wrong and do not work. For one thing WebDav would be mapped by using the FULL URL including HTTP. There are also some security problems. Read here for ideas: https://support.netdocuments.com/hc/en-us/articles/205212850-WebDAV-as-a-Mapped-Drive?mobile_site=true in Windows 10 there is also a “connect to a website” option in the map network drive window. Just do some research.

Comment: Apart from the question how to map to a WebDAV server I am wondering if the server on the phone is not blocked by a firewall or something. In powershell you can issue this command to test that: `Test-NetConnection 192.168.0.11 -port 8080`

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld That test succeeds and takes about 5 seconds. Trying to map the drive fails instantly (i.e. no delay at all).

Comment: I have a similar problem, and I couldn't fix it after hours of troubleshooting. So I tried the free RaiDrive (https://www.raidrive.com) which worked immediately.