# "Network path could not be found" on a drive that works from everywhere else

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, hard-drive

I have a network drive (Seagate Central) on my network that I've been using for a long time with no issues from multiple Windows 7, Linux, Android, and iOS machines, and it is currently still working just fine with those machines.

However, I just got a new computer (Lenovo Thinkpad P73) running Windows 10, and when I attempt to connect to the drive, it says "network path could not be found". I don't have any other Windows 10 systems to test it on so I am not sure if it works on other Windows 10 machines.

It's strange because the drive shows up in the Network view, and when I attempt to connect by specifying a path in File Explorer it does ask me for credentials -- but then it gives that error.

The error occurs whether I double click the drive in the Network view, or select it in the drive mapping dialog, or enter the path manually.

The error occurs with both the network name and the IP address of the drive, I thought using the IP address might fix it but, no luck.

I'm ... not really sure what else to do. I can't find any more detailed error messages, and the error is so generic that there are too many unrelated search results that don't really apply (e.g. "make sure the drive is plugged in" :-/ ).

I found a very similar looking question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1412646/map-network-drive-the-network-path-could-not-be-found) although it has been around for a while and has no answers; that's about the most relevant thing I could find.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because your network drive uses SMB1, and SMB1 is deprecated. It's not working on your Windows 10 computer because since Windows 10 1709, SMB1 [is disabled by default](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/smbv1-not-installed-by-default-in-windows).

You should consider upgrading your network drive to (at least) SMB2. Microsoft provides [a way](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3) to enable SMB1 on Windows 10, but I don't recommend doing so because this protocol has known security issues.

Comment: That was it! I enabled it through PowerShell and it works just fine now. I'm not too concerned about SMB security for this, it's all behind a hardware firewall and I'm going to be replacing that drive with something better soon anyways. I wish that error message would have been a little more relevant. Thanks!